# Is the following proof correct in regards to Indecomposable group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

The following is taken from: [here](https://askfilo.com/user-question-answers-algebra-1/prove-that-a-group-is-indecomposable-if-and-only-if-whenever-35373532343437)

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

It concerns the proof of the following theorem:

**Prove that a group $G$ is indecomposable if and only if whenever $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups such that $G=H\times K,$ then $H=\langle e \rangle$ or $K=\langle e \rangle$.**

> Proof:  Part 1:  Indecomposable implies $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1.$
>
> Assume $G$ is an indecomposable group.  Let $H$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G$ is the direct product of the subgroups $H$ and $K.$  We need to show that either $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1$
>
> Assume for the sake of contradiction, that neither $H$ nor $K$ is the trivial subgroup, which means both $|H|>1$ and $|K|>1.$  Since $G$ is the direct product of $H$ and $K,$ we can write every element of $G$ as a product $hk,$ where $h$ is from $H$ and $K$ is from $K.$
>
> Consider two non-identity elemetns, $h_1\in H$ and $k_1\in K,$ Such that $h_1\neq e$ and $k_1\neq e.$  Then their product $h_1k_1$ is a non-identity element in $G$ (as $G$ is indecomposable).  Now, consider the element ${h^{-1}}_1(h_1k_1),$ which is equal to ${h^{-1}}_1h_1k_1=ek_1=k_1.$  Since $K$ is a normal subgroup, products of elements in $K$ and inverses of elements in $K$ are also in $K,$ so the eleemnt $k_1$ should also be in the product $HK.$
>
> Part 2: $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1.$ implies $G$ is indecomposable.
>
> Now, assume that for any normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ of $G$ such that $G$ is the direct product of the subgroups $H$ and $K,$ either $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1.$  We need to show that $G$ is indecomposable.
>
> To show $G$ is indecomposable, suppose, for the sake of contradiction, that $G$ is decomposable.  Then there exist nontrival subgroups $H'$ and $K'$ of $G,$ such that $G$ is the direct product of $H'$ and $K'.$  Since $H'$ and $k'$ are subgroups, they are also normal subgroups in the direct product.
>
> Now, according to the assumption, either $|H'|=1$ or $|K'|=1.$  But this contradicts our choice of $H'$ and $K'$ as nontrivial subgroups, so the assumption that $G$ is decomposable must be false.  Thus, $G$ is indecomposable.
>
> We have shown that, for a group $ G$, if it is indecomposable, then for any noraml subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $G$ is the direct product of the subgroups $H$ and $K,$ either $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1.$  We have also show the reverse direction, i.e., if for normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $G$ is the direct product of the subgroups $H$ and $K,$ either $|H|=1$ or $|K|=1,$ then $G$ is indecomposable.  Hence, the proof is completele.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I would like to get a second opinion if the above proof of the stated theorem is correct.  I looked over and all the steps seem to check out.  The reason I ask is that the student solutions manual for the problem simply states that:  "The is a straight forward check of the definition."  I am not sure if to take that to mean that the solution seems to be meremly going over the definition or is the reader suppose to do something more like give a proof similar to the one above.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you meant to write $h_1^{-1}$ and not $h_1^1$?

Comment: @Divide1918 i fixed the typo.  Thank you for pointing it out.  Do you know if the quoted proof is correct?

Comment: How does $K$ is a normal subgroup (also, of what group?) implies $k_1\in HK$? And how exactly does that prove the forward implication required?

Comment: @Divide1918 $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G.$ I have added more details from the proof in the above link.  I think the proof don't consistently maintain that $J$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G.$ in different places.

Comment: You still didn’t answer my question though?

Comment: @Davide1918 from your comments, I think there are gaps in reasoning for the proof?  Is that correct.  I copy the proof verbatium.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150486/discussion-between-divide1918-and-seth).

Comment: @Divide1918 thank you so very much for answering all my questions in chat.  I did not see your last reply since I had to go to bed.   Have yourself and your family a merry christmas and happy holidays. :)